# How to change sign of any no. by clicking button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, calculator

I am making a calculator app where I want to change the sign of no. by clicking a button.

```
  buttonplusminus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(edittext==null){
                edittext.setText("");
            }
            else {
                Value1=Float.parseFloat(edittext.getText()+ "");
                 if (Value1<0){

                 }

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: so you want to change positive number to negative number and vice versa ?

Comment: yes sir, plz solve  my problem

Comment: always start variable names with small letters . use `value1` instead of  `Value1`

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the number with -1 to reverse the symbol and set it again to edit text

```
buttonplusminus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(edittext.getText()==null){
            edittext.setText("");
        }
        else {
            value1=Float.parseFloat(edittext.getText());
            value1*=-1
                edittext.setText(String.valueOf(value1))

        }
    }
});
```